# Why does PHP script returns empty string to android on server?

Tags: java, php, android

I have made an android app with PHP back-end that works right on the localhost.
but, when I upload it on a server returns an empty string instead of for example "ok". I have put all the permission to 777 but it doesn't work.

one of the PHP script :

```
<?php  

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        require_once('dbConnect.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM coachtbl WHERE kodemelli =
        '$username'
        AND password='$password'";
        $r = @mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
         if($num_rows>0){
            echo ("ok");}
         else{
             echo (mysqli_error($con));
         }
        @mysqli_close($con); 
    }

 ?>
```

And this is my android code :

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.login_Api, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (s.trim().equals("ok")) {
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this , MainPage.class));
                    kodemelli=kode.getText().toString().trim();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "username or password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loading.dismiss();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", kode.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("password", pass.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue =
                Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are You sure You're making a POST request from Your android phone ? Can You past the android code ? Is the file on the server accessible from the internet ?

Comment: Yes I am sure about it. Also I post the android code

Comment: Did you use Postman for making a post to Your Web server ? What the result correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by Postman ??

Comment: To make a POST request to Your page like with this website. https://reqbin.com/

Comment: It returns **Status:
200 (OK)
Time:
332 ms
Size:
0 kb**

Comment: And did You put username and password in the post request ? did You get the expected result "ok" ?

Comment: You have to choose "Form URL Encoded" from the List and put a content like this: "username=myname
password=mypassword". Please paste the result in Your question

Comment: also if You can send me the url where your post is located i can check it.

Comment: Any update with postman ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your URL `Config.login_Api` settings are wrong. Check for '/' backslashes missing at the end of URL: like 'www.hello.com/'

Another possible issue is that your PHP webserver is misconfigured.
Check for .htaccess settings or missing PHP Deamon running on the remote Webserver.

Comment: I checked it and it was correct, also if I have enter the wrong domain I think I would have faced with ```com.android.Volley.ClientError``` . Wouldn't   I?

Comment: more info is needed. please complete the question. If the api is publicly accessible please share the link so I could check.

Comment: also paste the content of Your htaccess file if the php file is hosted on Apache server

Answer (score -1):

Replace `POST` by `GET`

You are executing a wrong HTTP method request.

Comment: I tried it but I get same result (an empty String).